# Get the bad smell out of sheep wool

Tags: gear, gear-care, winter, jackets

*Note: This question might be a little offtopic. Kill it if necessary.*

I've always had "THC" outdoor jackets which are knitted sheep wool jackets. However, they stink like a stable. Normally I put them outside for a week and the smell is gone.

This time the smell refuses to leave the jacket. It's been outside for two weeks now and still stinks a little bit.

Is there something to speed up the process of removing the smell? Or something to get rid of the smell immediately?

Comment: Have you tried washing it?

Comment: @Roddy Yes ... Doesn't have any effects :/

Comment: What is THC? Have you tried sprinkling baking soda over it, working it in with a brush, leaving it and then vacuuming the baking soda out?   (How old is this jacket?)

Comment: @ab2 I'll try this - thank you! :) I've bought it two weeks ago (+ storage time of course). THC is a German brand called "THC Natural Line". http://www.thc-natural-line.de/

Comment: Experiment with just sprinking the baking soda on and rubbing it in gently.  You don't want to abrade a new jacket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you think of the amount of wool we normally wear and use - and how it behaves - the only reason a wool garment would stink is that the wool hasn't been properly processed. This document is bit of an eye-opener.

https://oecotextiles.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/what-does-organic-wool-mean/

> On average, each ton of greasy wool contains:
>
> - 150 KG woolgrease (when refined this is known as lanolin)
> - 40 KG **suint**
> - 150 KG dirt
> - 20 KG vegetable matter
> - 640 KG wool fiber

*Suint*?, I hear you ask...  **dried perspiration of sheep deposited in the wool and rich in potassium salts** http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suint

I'd return it for a refund if it's just weeks old. Wool clothes shouldn't stink - in fact, the anti-bacterial properties of lanolin are one of the main benefits.